# More Than 50K Categories and Wordpress Admin Panel Stop Showing Categories and Posts

Tags: posts, categories, database

I've imported more thank 50K categories into WordPress. Now, when I open Wordpress admin panel, category page takes a lot of time to load and once loading is complete in the browser, nothing shows up in on the category page.
Then I open the posts page and it doesn't load posts too. Frontend looks normal, category page loading, posts loading with normal speed.

Then I thought there should be an error while importing the categories but instead of digging into it, it decided to delete all the categories using the database and then again imported 10K categories. Then I checked the WordPress admin panel, e.g posts and category page, everything loads normally and everything shows up there. Then I imported next 30K categories and again the same thing happened.
Any idea why?

Comment: Did you try upgrading to a stronger server?

Comment: No, I'm on a shared server by the time now but later once backend is complete, I'll upgrade to VPS. So more resources are needed!